# Bundler couldn't find compatable versions on bundle install in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I have cloned an existing project and trying to run it in my system.
Since this is the first time I don't have any Gemfile.lock file in my directory.
I tried running bundle install and the following errors occur:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    liquid_markdown (= 0.2.2) was resolved to 0.2.2, which depends on
      actionmailer (>= 4.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 4.1.6)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    gon (= 6.4.0) was resolved to 6.4.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0.20)

    jquery-datatables-rails (= 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)

    rails-api was resolved to 0.4.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.2.11)

    redis-rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-actionpack (>= 5.0, < 6) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 4.0, < 7)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.3, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionview":
  In Gemfile:
    liquid_markdown (= 0.2.2) was resolved to 0.2.2, which depends on
      actionview (>= 4.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      actionview (= 4.1.6)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    acts_as_api (= 1.0.1) was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)

    carrierwave was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.2) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    audited (= 4.8.0) was resolved to 4.8.0, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0, < 5.3)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.1.6)

    squeel was resolved to 1.2.3, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    acts_as_api (= 1.0.1) was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    carrierwave was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.2) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)

    redis-rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-activesupport (>= 5.0, < 6) was resolved to 5.2.0, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3, < 7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "coffee-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)

    chosen-rails was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
      coffee-rails (>= 3.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
        i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)

    gon (= 6.4.0) was resolved to 6.4.0, which depends on
      i18n (>= 0.7)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      mime-types (>= 1.16)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.2) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      mime-types

    rest-client (~> 1.7.2) was resolved to 1.7.3, which depends on
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mimemagic":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip (~> 4.3.2) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)

Could not find gem 'mimemagic (= 0.3.0)', which is required by gem 'paperclip (~> 4.3.2)', in
any of the sources.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
        rack (~> 1.5.2)

    acts_as_api (= 1.0.1) was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      rack (>= 1.1.0)

    resque-scheduler was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      resque (>= 1.26) was resolved to 1.27.4, which depends on
        sinatra (>= 0.9.2) was resolved to 1.4.8, which depends on
          rack-protection (~> 1.4) was resolved to 1.5.5, which depends on
            rack

    redis-rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-actionpack (>= 5.0, < 6) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
        redis-rack (>= 1, < 3) was resolved to 2.0.6, which depends on
          rack (>= 1.5, < 3)

    request_store (= 1.4.1) was resolved to 1.4.1, which depends on
      rack (>= 1.4)

    resque-scheduler was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      resque (>= 1.26) was resolved to 1.27.4, which depends on
        sinatra (>= 0.9.2) was resolved to 1.4.8, which depends on
          rack (~> 1.5)

    sass-rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0) was resolved to 3.7.2, which depends on
        rack (> 1, < 3)

    devise was resolved to 4.7.3, which depends on
      warden (~> 1.2.3) was resolved to 1.2.7, which depends on
        rack (>= 1.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6)

    bootstrap-tooltip-rails was resolved to 0.1, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.1)

    has_magic_fields (= 0.2.1) was resolved to 0.2.1, which depends on
      rails (>= 4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails (= 0.1.5) was resolved to 0.1.5, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0, < 5.1)

    bootstrap-slider-rails (= 9.2.0) was resolved to 9.2.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.0)

    coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0) was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)

    data-confirm-modal (= 1.2.0) was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.7.3, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.1.0)

    font-awesome-rails was resolved to 4.7.0.7, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2, < 7)

    jquery-datatables-rails (= 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      jquery-rails was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
        railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)

    jquery-tablesorter was resolved to 1.27.2, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2)

    momentjs-rails (= 2.15.1) was resolved to 2.15.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.1)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      railties (= 4.1.6)

    rails-api was resolved to 0.4.1, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2.11)

    sass-rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)

    chosen-rails was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
      sassc-rails (>= 2.1.2) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
        railties (>= 4.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "redis":
  In Gemfile:
    redis-namespace (= 1.5.3) was resolved to 1.5.3, which depends on
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)

    redis-rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-store (>= 1.2, < 2) was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
        redis (>= 2.2, < 5)

    resque-scheduler was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      redis (>= 3.3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "redis-namespace":
  In Gemfile:
    redis-namespace (= 1.5.3)

    resque-scheduler was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      resque (>= 1.26) was resolved to 1.27.4, which depends on
        redis-namespace (~> 1.3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "redis-store":
  In Gemfile:
    redis-rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-actionpack (>= 5.0, < 6) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
        redis-store (>= 1.1.0, < 2)

    redis-rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-activesupport (>= 5.0, < 6) was resolved to 5.2.0, which depends on
        redis-store (>= 1.3, < 2)

    redis-rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-store (>= 1.2, < 2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "resque":
  In Gemfile:
    resque

    resque-scheduler was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      resque (>= 1.26)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby

    bootstrap (~> 4.4.1) was resolved to 4.4.1, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.3.3)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0) was resolved to 1.17.3, which depends on
        ruby (>= 1.8.7)

    byebug (= 11.0.1) was resolved to 11.0.1, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.3.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.7.3, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.1.0)

    gon (= 6.4.0) was resolved to 6.4.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.2.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
        minitest (~> 5.1) was resolved to 5.14.4, which depends on
          ruby (>= 2.2, < 4.0)

    aws-sdk (< 2.0) was resolved to 1.67.0, which depends on
      aws-sdk-v1 (= 1.67.0) was resolved to 1.67.0, which depends on
        nokogiri (~> 1) was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
          ruby (>= 2.5.0)

    pg (= 0.21.0) was resolved to 0.21.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 2.0.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9.3)

    rest-client (~> 1.7.2) was resolved to 1.7.3, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9.2)

    sentry-raven (= 2.6.0) was resolved to 2.6.0, which depends on
      ruby (>= 1.9.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (= 5.0.6)

    jquery-datatables-rails (= 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      sass-rails

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)

    chosen-rails was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
      sassc-rails (>= 2.1.2) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
        sprockets (> 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)

    sass-rails (= 5.0.6) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

    chosen-rails was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
      sassc-rails (>= 2.1.2) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
        sprockets-rails

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tzinfo":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
        tzinfo (~> 1.1)

    resque-scheduler was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      rufus-scheduler (~> 3.2) was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
        fugit (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.6) was resolved to 1.4.4, which depends on
          et-orbi (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.8) was resolved to 1.2.4, which depends on
            tzinfo
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '0.21.0'

gem 'pushpad', '0.12.0'
gem 'gon', '6.4.0'

source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-datetimepicker'
end
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.6'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'has_magic_fields', '0.2.1'
gem 'bootstrap-tooltip-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-multiselect-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'multi-select-rails'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
gem 'request_store', '1.4.1'
gem 'plyr-rails'
gem "audited", '4.8.0'
gem 'jquery-datatables', '1.10.20'
gem 'telephone_number', '1.3.4'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'mini_racer'
gem 'acts_as_api', '1.0.1'
gem 'clipboard-rails'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'workflow'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.7.2'
gem 'httpclient'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'rails-api'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.4.1'
gem 'bootstrap_form', '2.7.0'
gem "cocoon"
gem 'chartkick', '2.2.4'
gem 'redis-rails', '5.0.2'
gem 'redis-namespace', "1.5.3"
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem "cancan", "1.6.10"
gem "figaro"
gem 'jquery-tablesorter'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'icheck-rails', '1.0.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-slider-rails', '9.2.0'
gem 'haml', '4.0.7'
gem 'data-confirm-modal', "1.2.0"
gem "momentjs-rails", "2.15.1"
gem "bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails", "0.1.5"
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3.2"
gem "underscore-rails"
gem "gmaps4rails"
gem "jquery-datatables-rails", "3.3.0"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'resque'
gem 'resque-scheduler'
gem 'liquid_markdown', '0.2.2'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
group :production do
  gem 'zip'
  gem "sentry-raven", "2.6.0"
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'byebug', '11.0.1'
end
```

rvm list:

```
=* ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

gem env:

```
 RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/bala/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/bala/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/bala/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/bala/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/bala/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
     - /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/bala/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
     - /home/bala/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin
     - /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin
     - /usr/share/rvm/bin
     - /home/bala/.local/bin
     - /home/bala/anaconda3/condabin
     - /home/bala/.local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /snap/bin
     - /home/bala/.rvm/bin
     - /home/bala/.rvm/bin
     - /home/bala/.rvm/bin
```

bundler --version:
**Bundler version 1.17.3**

can someOne help me, I came to know that I have to use bundle version 1.17.3 (so there is no problem with bundle version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is all to do with `mimemagic`. More specifically, this error:

> Could not find gem 'mimemagic (= 0.3.0)', which is required by gem 'paperclip (~> 4.3.2)', in
> any of the sources.

There was a big drama recently in the ruby community, as [all old versions of this gem were suddenly *yanked* (**hard**-deleted) from rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/mimemagic/versions), after the author became aware that the library had been incorrectly licensed as MIT, rather than GPLv2.

Multiple discussions about this easily findable on google (if you know what you're searching for, of course!) such as [here](https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic/issues/148), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/mc5bpe/mimemagic_versions_prior_to_036_have_been_yanked/) and [here](https://dev.to/cseeman/what-s-up-with-mimemagic-breaking-everything-he1).

An ideal fix would be to update whatever libraries are necessary to use the newer `mimemagic` version. (Perhaps it's just `paperclip` in your case?) I can't say for sure without seeing your full `Gemfile.lock`.

But if that's not feasible right now, and you just want to get an installation working with [`v0.3.0` of `mimemagic`](https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic/commit/a4b038c6c1b9d76dac33d5711d28aaa9b4c42c66), you could always [look through the git history](https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic/commits/master?after=af5a9b1c5b774e65fd84bd7ca4239a9f3eba2039+104&branch=master) and pin that version's commit in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mimemagic', git: 'https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic', ref: 'a4b038c6c1b9d76dac33d5711d28aaa9b4c42c66'
```

However, be aware that - as mentioned above - the old versions of this gem should really have been `GPLv2` licensed, not MIT licensed. For local development that's definitely not an issue; but for production deployment it *might* be a legal issue. I Am Not A Lawyer.

Comment: why gems such as actionmailer (which doesn't depend on mimemagic) also throwing an error ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't understand why the error message contains all of that other stuff. My guess is that the *yanked gem* created a poorly handled error path in bundler, which left it in a confused state about why it failed to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

In your project directory, try installing rails `gem install rails -v 4.1.6` and removing the version from the failing gems like (`liquid_markdown`, `gon`, etc..) then try running `bundle update` then `bundle clean --force`

I think this might be an issue because all the version of these gems are locked inside your Gemfile

Comment: didn't work.Getting same errors after bundle update

Comment: @Balavamsi i think this might be an issue caused by the locked versions in your Gemfile, updated the answer, let me know if it works